# Full width expanding div using 960 grid system?

Tags: css, 960.gs

How do you get a div that expands to the full size of the browser (no matter how you resize) while working with the 960 grid system? I can only think of something like this - but I don't like it because what if you have a background for the container_24 then you'd have to set it two times. The point is, I want everything else working under the container_24 even the text inside the full expanding div.

```
<div class="container_24">
    <!-- stuff -->
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 940px;">
       Hello
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container_24">
   <!-- more stuff -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `z-index` value on both the container and expanding div and having the `z-index` value for the expanding div larger than the container will lift it out. You then need to set the `position` of the expanding div to `absolute` and then it will expand out of the container. I'm sure there are some cases where this won't work/cut it though.